# Shorten the argument's "path"

Tags: vb.net, enums, arguments

A short example of the problem I have:

```vb
Namespace ActivityLogger
    Public Class XmlLoggerWriter

        Enum XmlLoggerType
            Information
            Warning
            Fault
        End Enum

        Friend Shared Sub WriteToLog(ByVal Type As XmlLoggerType)
            'some code here
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

And here is the call to the above sub:

```vb
Call WriteToLog(ActivityLogger.XmlLoggerWriter.XmlLoggerType.Information)
```

As you can see, the argument passed is quite lenghty, even though I have imported `XML_Writer.ActivityLogger.XmlLoggerWriter`.

I was hoping to get just the `XmlLoggerType.Information` part or even just the `Information`. Is there any way this can be shorten down? Because this will be used a lot throughout the code, and I like it to be simple and easily readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import also `XmlLoggerWriter`:

```
Imports ActivityLogger.XmlLoggerWriter
```

Then this works:

```
WriteToLog(XmlLoggerType.Information)
```

If you also import

```
Imports ActivityLogger.XmlLoggerWriter.XmlLoggerType
```

you can even write

```
WriteToLog(Information)
```